# Validate object using json schema in C#

Tags: c#, json, jsonschema

I'm trying to use a json shema to validate an incoming objet parameter in a C# api.
Here is my api proto :

```
void BuildSqlQueryFromSegment(JoinDefinition jsonDef);
```

JsonDefinition is a complex objects, with lots of properties. Properties values are depending each other, this is why simple validateur attribute like Required, Min, Max can't be used here.

One solution would be to pass a string instead of the type object :

```
void BuildSqlQueryFromSegment(string jsonDef) {
    // Check shema here, using Json.NET Schema
    // if ok, deserialize and get the JsonDefition object instance
}
```

I'm able to implment this quite easily, but i find this solution not smart.

What i'm looking for is something like this :

```
void BuildSqlQueryFromSegment([SchemaValidation('MySchemaResourceHere')] JoinDefinition jsonDef);
```

Does this kind of attribute exist ? If not, how can i implement it ? How can i act on incoming response json string to check the schema ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: newtonsoft's json.net library has a schema validator but it is not free. you may have more info on http://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema . Still, I have never used it so I do not know if it will meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create JsonSchema from JoinDefinition class

```
        JsonSchemaGenerator schemaGenerator = new JsonSchemaGenerator{ };
        var o = new JoinDefinition ();
        JsonSchema Objschema = schemaGenerator.Generate(o.GetType());
```

than get Jsonschema from string

```
        JObject jObject= JObject.Parse(JsonString);

        bool valid = jObject.IsValid(Objschema);
```

If JsonString schema match from class json schema it would return true else false

You will have to use below namespace

```
       using Newtonsoft.Json;
       using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
       using Newtonsoft.Json.Schema;
```

Comment: you can catch error with out keyword
IList<string> errorMessages;
            bool valid = jObject.IsValid(schema, out Objschema);

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already knew this, My question was about wrapping this code in an attribute, to avoid starting from a string. How can i implement an attribute in wich i can insert the above code ?